# Getting System.Reflection.TargetInvocationException for a call to Mock.Object

Tags: .net, asp.net-core, moq, xunit, asp.net-core-signalr

I'm not sure as to why this is happening but when I am trying to call `userIdProvider.GetUserId(_mockHubConnectionContext.Object)` it throws `System.Reflection.TargetInvocationException` at `_mockHubConnectionContext.Object`.
My constructor for the test class includes:

```cs
_mockConnectionContext = new Mock<ConnectionContext>();
_mockLoggerFactory = new Mock<ILoggerFactory>();
_mockHubConnectionContext = new Mock<HubConnectionContext>(_mockConnectionContext.Object, new HubConnectionContextOptions(), _mockLoggerFactory.Object);
```

The method signature for UserIdProvider.GetUserId() is:

```cs
public string GetUserId(HubConnectionContext hubConnectionContext)
```

To give you some more context, this started happening when we tried to move from .NET Core 3.1 to .NET 6.0.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved this issue quite a while back. Seeing no concrete answer to the question I decided to post the answer myself.

Changing the connection context passed to `Mock<HubConnectionContext>` from a mock to some concrete implementation like `DefaultConnectionContext` solved the issue. More details as to why this was causing an error can be found [here](https://github.com/dotnet/aspnetcore/issues/39484).

Answer (score 0):

`TargetInvocationException` is a wrapper around an exception thrown by something else, so the first thing you'll want to do is look at `InnerException` to check the message \ stack trace.

That will hopefully point you in the right direction for where the problem is.

Comment: This is more like a useful comment than an answer.